# How can I access a List<object> from appsettings.Json?

Tags: c#, asp.net, appsettings

In my appsettings.json I have a field like this

```
    "MyFields" : [
    {
    "name":"one",
    "type":"type1"
    "parameters":[{"key":"url","value":"myurl.com"}, {"key":"data","value":"mydata"}]
    },
    {
    "name":"two",
    "type":"type2"
    ...
    ..
    and so on
    }
    ]
```

I have made a class Myfield with the following properties:

```
    public class MyField
        {
            [JsonProperty]
            public string? name { get; set; }
    
            [JsonProperty]
            public string? type { get; set; }
    
            [JsonProperty]
            public IDictionary<string,string>? parameters { get; set; }
        }
```

And I am trying to access it in an other class using the config, like this :

```
    //config is the configuration
       var myFields = config.GetSection("MyFields").Get<List<MyField>>();
```

the problem is that myFields turn out to be empty. But when I do the same thing by eliminating the "parameters" field then it works like a charm.

I know its something related to improper matching but it'll be great to get some help.

Comment: Can you change the JSON format?

Answer (score 0):

you have a bug, should be

```
    public Dictionary<string, string>[] parameters { get; set; }

     //or
    public  List<Dictionary<string, string>> parameters { get; set; }
```

but maybe this would be more effiecient

```
public  List<KeyValue> parameters { get; set; }
....

public class KeyValue
{
    public string key {get; set;}
    public string value {get; set;}
 }
```